# Set array value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a page with three clickleable divs. When user clicks a div, a js function is called, sends an XMLHttpRequest and the retrieved info is loaded below that div. If user clicks the same div again, info is hidden. HTML code:

```
<div><input name="Master" type="Submit" class="My_Class" value="The First Group" onclick="WhatToShow('Group1');"></div>
<div id="Group1"></div>
<div><input name="Master" type="Submit" class="My_Class" value="The Second Group" onclick="WhatToShow('Group2');"></div>
<div id="Group2"></div>
<div><input name="Master" type="Submit" class="My_Class" value="The Third Group" onclick="WhatToShow('Group3');"></div>
<div id="Group3"></div>
```

JS code:

```
<script>
function WhatToShow(My_Group) {
    if (typeof TheStatus === 'undefined' || TheStatus == 0) {
        TheStatus=1;
    }
    else {
        TheStatus=0;    
    }

    if (TheStatus==0) {
        document.getElementById(My_Group).style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(My_Group).style.display = 'inline';
    }
        //XMLHttpRequest here
        //loading in document.getElementById(My_Group)
}
</script>
```

**My problem:** if user clicks a div, Info appears. But for showing info from another div (without "closing" the first), he has to click twice. And that is because ot the variable `TheStaus`. Is there a way of defining something as `TheStaus[My_Group]`? In that way I would define a "variable" for each group.

Comment: Are you setting the variable `TheStatus` using `var` keyword?

Comment: @abhisek nope. Should I?

Comment: Are you asking if JavaScript has arrays or objects?

Comment: yes use an object, initialize with `TheStatus = {};` then you can write `TheStatus[MyGroup] = 0;` etc.

Comment: @CMArg yes you should. `TheStatus` is hitting the global scope.

Comment: @Matthias You make it to work! Thanks a lot! (If you post the answer I can accept it...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes use an object, initialize with `TheStatus = {};` then you can write `TheStatus[MyGroup] = 0;` etc.

E.g.

```
<script>
var TheStatus = {};
function WhatToShow(My_Group) {
    if (typeof TheStatus[My_Group] === 'undefined' || TheStatus[My_Group] == 0) {
        TheStatus[My_Group]=1;
    }
    else {
        TheStatus[My_Group]=0;    
    }

    if (TheStatus[My_Group]==0) {
        document.getElementById(My_Group).style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(My_Group).style.display = 'inline';
    }
        //XMLHttpRequest here
        //loading in document.getElementById(My_Group)
}
</script>
```

If you want some extra general programming advice, it is tradition to reserve capital letters in the beginning of variable names for classes, libraries and such (and ALLCAPS often used for constants). I would recommend not capitalizing any of your variables. In addition I would recommend using either camelCase or snake_case, not both.

With these slight modifications your code would become

```
<script>
var theStatus = {};
function whatToShow(myGroup) {
    if (typeof theStatus[myGroup] === 'undefined' || theStatus[myGroup] == 0) {
        theStatus[myGroup]=1;
    }
    else {
        theStatus[myGroup]=0;    
    }

    if (theStatus[myGroup]==0) {
        document.getElementById(myGroup).style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(myGroup).style.display = 'inline';
    }
        //XMLHttpRequest here
        //loading in document.getElementById(myGroup)
}
</script>
```

You can see now the stackoverflow highlighter is a bit more tame.

Comment: @Mattias excuse me my ignorance (I'm a newbee), but your code works perfectly for me if `var TheStatus={}` is defined **outside** the function. Is that a bad habit or bad practice?

Comment: no need to excuse ignorance. You are right, for your scenario it should probably be outside actually, otherwise, it is reset each time the function is called and does nothing.

Comment: I edited my answer. When you define it outside the function like this, you are making it global. Global variables should always be used with caution. For example, if you define TheStatus like this, if you would use some other javascript code, it would also see your TheStatus variable, and if they themselves used a TheStatus variable, they could change yours. That is why in general it is good practice to avoid globals. Which you could do here by for example not using the status in code, but change the class of the div to be hidden or visible. However, I think you're fine.

Comment: I learned three things today: how to make my code working, main facts about global variables, and "general programming advice" about caps. Good for a newbee!

Comment: and I learned what the hell a "phytoalexin" is. I'd call us even.

Answer (score 0):

```
js code


<script>
function WhatToShow(My_Group) {
    document.getElementById(Group1).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(Group2).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(Group3).style.display = 'none';
    if (typeof TheStatus === 'undefined' || TheStatus == 0) {
        TheStatus=1;
    }
    else {
        TheStatus=0;    
    }

    if (TheStatus==0) {
        document.getElementById(My_Group).style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(My_Group).style.display = 'inline';
    }
        //XMLHttpRequest here
        //loading in document.getElementById(My_Group)
}
</script>
```

Comment: 1. Just posting code without any kind of explanations is not a good way to answer. 2. This doesn't even work, `Group1` etc. are not defined variables

Comment: Thanks Nishant, but this is not solving my problem. Your code closes previous group (edited to `document.getElementById('Group1')`), but on first click, `TheStatus` is set to 1 (show), but on second (if is in another div) `TheStatus` is set to 0 --> display none.

Comment: wait a minute please

Comment: check below code and modify according to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a single scalar value to test for the hidden / shown property of multiple elements, use an array or object to maintain the status of each and every element.

```
function WhatToShow(My_Group) {

    var shown = {
        "Group1": false,
        "Group2": false,
        "Group3": false
    };
    var currentEltId = this.getAttribute('id');

    if (shown[currentEltId]) {
        this.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        this.style.display = 'inline';
    }

    shown[currentEltId] = !shown[currentEltId]

    //XMLHttpRequest here
    //loading in document.getElementById(My_Group)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function WhatToShow(My_Group) {
        document.getElementById("Group1").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("Group2").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("Group3").style.display = 'none';
    $("#"+My_Group).show();
        
    }
```

```css
#Group1,#Group2,#Group3{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input name="Master" type="Submit" class="My_Class" value="The First Group" onclick="WhatToShow('Group1');"></div>
<div id="Group1">khhd</div>
<div><input name="Master" type="Submit" class="My_Class" value="The Second Group" onclick="WhatToShow('Group2');"></div>
<div id="Group2">ddd1</div>
<div><input name="Master" type="Submit" class="My_Class" value="The Third Group" onclick="WhatToShow('Group3');"></div>
<div id="Group3">ddd2</div>
```

Comment: This is **still** lacking any kind of explanations and as such is not a good answer

Comment: Use this code and modify it according to your requirement

Comment: default all divs are display:none , when you clicked any div it will show you that div data.

Answer (score 0):

`TheStatus` has global scope, and you've set it up to toggle every time you hit a div, no matter what div is hit. So to display one div, you hit a div, toggling `TheStatus` to 1, and then the next time you hit a div - any div - `TheStatus` toggles back to zero, making all divs disappear. You have to hit a div yet another time to make it appear.

I think you're on to the right idea, namely to create a `TheStatus` for each group.

Maybe try something like this:

```
<script>
  var TheStatus = [0,0,0];
  function WhatToShow(My_Group) {
    // Toggle the TheStatus element corresponding to My_Group
    switch (My_Group) {
      case 'Group1': TheStatus[0] = (TheStatus[0] == 1) ? 0 : 1; break;
      case 'Group2': TheStatus[1] = (TheStatus[1] == 1) ? 0 : 1; break;
      case 'Group3': TheStatus[2] = (TheStatus[2] == 1) ? 0 : 1; break;
    }
    // Now set the display according to TheStatus of each element
    TheStatus.forEach(function(status,i) {
      var visibility = (status == 1) ? 'inline' : 'none';
      var groupId = 'Group' + (i+1).toString(); // construct group ID
      document.getElementById(groupId).style.display = visibility;
    });
    //XMLHttpRequest here
    //loading in document.getElementById(My_Group)
  }
</script>
```

I'm sure the above could be optimized, especially considering that you may have any number of groups, but I think you get the point. Essentially, every time a div is hit, it causes its respective element to toggle its visibility, and then you re-do the logic for the entire group of divs.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I didn't try your code, but the idea is similar to Matthias above. Thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

you can use Bootstrap accordion. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion